# Efficient mutable byte array in native Lua

Tags: compression, lua

I am trying to make an efficient implementation of an LZ77 decoder in native Lua (i.e. no C library, and no dependencies on non-core Lua libraries) - see [liblzg](http://liblzg.bitsnbites.eu).

For loading and parsing the binary file, a Lua string works perfectly, and with good performance (e.g. using the s:byte(k) method). However, for creating the decoded output data, strings are not very optimal, since they are immutable, and string concatenation tends to take lots and lots of time when the output becomes large.

The decoder must be able to:

- Append one byte to the output at a time (up to millions of times)
- Read (more or less random access) from the output buffer

What are the best options? The size of the output data is known before hand, so it can be pre-allocated.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why can't you use the C library? Is this an educational exercise or needed in a sandboxed Lua environment?

Comment: It's more of an educational exercise (I want to see the performance, and how the techniques differ between a low level compiled language and a managed script environment). Also, I imagine that having a pure Lua implementation would make it way easier to deploy.

Comment: Perfect question. Btw I'm not the unique who had the same idea

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Sounds like a perfect job for `table.concat`
your output is just a table of bytes.

When you need to copy, you do it as you normally would for a table.
eg:

```
for i=#output-5,9 do output[#output+1]=output[i] end
```

When you finally are done with the output stream, convert it to a string with `str=table.concat(output)`

Comment: What's the performance penalty of a large table? I suppose it's actually a table of numbers (i.e. doubles), so just the value would be 8:1 in size, and then there's the table index overhead. - I will test it.  Also, would I gain anything from preallocating the output table (since the size is known)?

Comment: Out of curiosity: How efficient is table.concat? Say, I have 1,000,000 table elements - would there be any point in doing some sort of recursive concatenation (1+1, 1+1, 1+1, .... 100+100, 100+100, etc) so that you don't end up in doing 999,997+1, 999,998+1 etc?

Comment: WORKS! (speed: 3 MB/s, compared to 300 MB/s for the C version, OK) I also got a speed increase by keeping track of the output length in a separate variable instead of doing #output (which is a costly operation for tables). Not sure about memory consumption though, but I consider it: problem solved.

Comment: table.concat is very efficient; it is actually the MOST effcient concatenation you can do in lua. Keeping your #output in another variable is also good practice (though It can make things slightly unreadable)

Answer (score 10):

Avoid string concatenation: save output strings to a table and write all strings in it at the end. If you're concerned about the table getting too big, flush it periodically.
See http://www.lua.org/pil/11.6.html

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not solve the problem of doing random access to the buffer. One operation that has to be supported is (for example): "pick 9 bytes starting 5 bytes back in the output buffer and append it to the output buffer" (yes, the copy can overlap itself!).

Comment: @marcus256 The approach @lhf proposes would still work in that case. You just need to right some functions to abstract those operations on a table of strings. Perhaps you should 'flush' the table to a single string each time an overlapped read/write needs to be occur, or does that kill your performance again?

Comment: I suppose that would kill performance (it's done quite frequently). I'm currently thinking about a hybrid of the table-of-strings and table-of-bytes suggested by @daurnimator: use a "top" table-of-bytes until it fills, say 1024 bytes, and then convert it to a string and append it to a table-of-strings, where each string is exactly 1024 bytes, making for easy indexing.